# How to align plots (ggplot2) horizontally?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, alignment, gridextra

Hello R and ggplot2 community!

I would like to horizontally align two plots, produced with `ggplot2`. One has both facets (and facet strips!) and legend, but the second hasn't. They share the same Y axis, which I would like to align. I'm ok to vertically align plots using their grobs' widths, but I couldn't figure it out with heights.

Here is a piece of code to support my question.

```
library( ggplot2 )
library( gridExtra )

plot_1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(
    data = iris,
    aes(
      x = Petal.Length,
      y = Petal.Width,
      colour = Sepal.Length 
      ) 
    ) +
  facet_grid(
    . ~ Species 
    ) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom"
    )

plot_2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(
    data = iris,
    aes(
      x = Sepal.Width,
      y = Petal.Width
      )
    )

g1 <- ggplotGrob( plot_1 )
g2 <- ggplotGrob( plot_2 )

# Here, how to manipulate grobs to get plot_2 scaled to the plot_1's Y axis? (ie, with an empty area right of the plot_1's legend)

grid.arrange( g1, g2, ncol = 2 )
```

Do you know how to manipulate grobs' heights before `grid.arrange()`? (Any other suggestion is welcome!)
Additionally, how to assign, say, two thirds of the total area to `plot_1`?

Note also that my real plots actually feature a `coord_flip()`, but I assumed it's not relevant for this question.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to create a blank panel:

```
blank<-grid.rect(gp=gpar(col="white"))
```

Then use grid.arrange in order to create a two column grid in which the second column actually consists of three rows.

```
grid.arrange(g1, arrangeGrob(blank,g2,blank,ncol=1,
heights=c(0.2,0.9,0.2)),ncol=2)
```

Playing around with the `heights` argument should provide us with the desired result.

Regarding your additional question the `heights` and `widths`arguments of `grid.arrange`should prove quite useful there aswell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pewi! Your advice of using the `widths` argument works perfectly. Your idea of using a blank panel is good, but the output depends on the final plot (and file) dimensions. I'm looking for a 'stricter' solution. Instead of hard-coding heights for blank panels, could it help to use the heights of the facet strip, the legend, and the legend skip?

Comment: It would quite easily be possible to append the data required for `plot_2`to the dataset you use for  `plot_1` and have `facet_grid()`do all your aligning for you. However that would also mean losing direct control of width using `grid.arrange`

Comment: `dat = iris; dat$Species = "All"; iris2 = rbind(dat,iris)` Then simply substitute `iris` with `iris2`in the code for `plot_1`

Comment: That is again a nice idea, however, the `plot_1` and `plot_2` don't share the same X variable (and breaks, tick labels and axis labels). The X variables of my real plots actually have different units and span. Could `facet_grid()` account for this difference?